# Ubuntu gets stuck at this after upgrading to 18.04: TSC_DEADLINE

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

I am extremely new to Ubuntu, and upgraded my OS for the first time.  It seemed to go fine until I rebooted and came face to face with this error:

```
TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)
```

I so far have tried using the recovery option, but I'm not sure if my GRUB is up to date because the recovery mode seems to display earlier versions of my Ubuntu boot.  Also, in other questions they have used commands and such, but I don't know how to run them when I can't even boot into my Ubuntu install.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Update also affected me, i cant run Ubuntu GUI

Comment: I would comment on the above that N0rbert pointed out instead of making a new post, but I do not have enough reputation at the moment to do so.

Comment: You just posted a comment, Dave.  What's wrong?

Comment: This is my own post, so I believe that is an exception as opposed to the answered question above.